# Update an entity in a list inside a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

```
username = {
    1:['Satinder',43000,'855799170'],
    2:['Rishabh',45000,'8557999170'],
    3:['Aman',47000,'8557999170']
}

balance = username[1][1]

amt = 20000

balance = balance - amt
```

How do I update balance at `username[1][1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be more efficient:

```
username[1][1] -= amt ## Replace everything after the declaration of your username dictionary with this code
```

EDIT: If you want the username dictionary to be saved after you close the program, you need to write it to a `.txt` file before you close the program.

Like this:

```
with open("your_data.txt", "r") as myFile:
    myFile.write(username)
```

Comment: sir i did this but the dictionary doesnot update when i run my program again

Comment: actually i am working on a project related to cash withdrawls so i need to update this entity in the dictionary permanently after deducting the withdrawl it runs fine for once but when i run the program again to check my balance it shows the same amount because it doesent update in the dictionary permanently it only stays till the execution of the first time

Answer (score 0):

u can save dict in Cache.
when record created key will generate dict as an value,
when record update key will update.